# Struts 1 binding dynamic values in html:checkbox value

Tags: checkbox, struts

Using [Apache Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts), I would like to bind a dynamic value to the html:checkbox value.

For instance I want to get userid in the form while submit the action.

Now

```
<html:checkbox property="userCheck" value="${searchedUsers.userId}"></html:checkbox>
```

so I just bind my userId value in the value attribute of check box.

`searchedUsers` is an arraylist which consist of user details include userId.

While submit the form I got `$searchedUser.userId` that is the value as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind that value 
we need to add `appserv-jstl.jar` in our `WEB-INF/lib folder`.

Then include following code in our page

'<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>'

Now it will work.